# DirectX 11 - ID3D11Texture2D -> массив байтов

Tags: c++, directx

Как в DirectX 11 и c++, имея D3D11Texture2D, получить массив байтов вида ARGB?
GetSurfaceLevel почему-то в DirectX 11 отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

ID3D11DeviceContext->Map и ID3D11DeviceContext->Unmap позволяют обращаться к данным. Смотрите подробнее справку по им, что бы узнать с какими параметрами использовать